# Creating CV_1UC1 Mat in OpenCV on Android

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I need to create an application with expensive real-time image processing methods (machine learning) and I need it to work as fast as possible.

I already capture gray images, which speeds up process about 100 times compared to RGB, but before processing, I still want to threshold it into binary matrix to speed up analysis. Unfortunately, it won't have a serious impact as long as it is stored in CV_8UC1 (8 bits unsigned in grayscale) instead of 1 bit in grayscale which would be sufficient to store color data.

Smallest Mat's I can find is CV_8UC1 (1 byte for pix). I have checked both in proposed ones and in "OpenCV 3.0 Computer Vision with Java" guide and it is not described.

Is it possible to create such Mat, or I have to work on byte arrays from now on?

Comment: The interface of the `Mat` class relies on being able to return pointers or references to the individual elements, so the lower bound is the smallest addressable element -- a byte.

Comment: You should also take into consideration that in most times it is more expensive to access variables which are less than your particular system's alignment (which is usually more than 1 byte). So unless you are using any particular algorithm which would manipulate with all those bits altogether rather than 1 operation per bit - you should not look into making your data shorter.

Comment: Both comments are more than satisfying :). Thank you.